# Moving Sharing buttons when blog posts change urls

Tags: url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Retrieve Facebook Like count after changing URL structure for entire website](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18978/retrieve-facebook-like-count-after-changing-url-structure-for-entire-website)

I want to move a blog from http://blog.wordfruit.com to http://wordfruit.com/blog

With permanent redirects to the new location from the old location.

The blog posts have sharing buttons (Linkedin Share, Tweet, Fb Like, +1)

Is it possible to move the sharing buttons, with their counts, to the new url locations?

Thanks,